# Why is a nullpointerexception occuring?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, priority-queue

I am implementing a priority queue using a stack, but a `NullPointerException` is occurring and I can't figure out why. I am trying to add an integer "1" by using the push method in the `MyStack` class. The error occurs at the add statement.

```
class MyStack<E> {
    private PriorityQueue<MyNode<E>> pq;
    int p =0;

    public void push(int j){
        p++;
        pq.add(new MyNode(j,p)); // error detected here
    }

    public MyNode pop(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }
        return pq.poll();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() { 
        return pq.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Edited: Reflects problem encountered in a proper manner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is complete it is simple: The member pq of your class MyStack is never initialized.

Comment: But when i initialize it, it is throwing me another error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: testing.MyNode cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Comment: Did you pass your Comparator in the constructor of the PriorityQueue? If the PriorityQueue has no Comparator it will assume that the entries themselves are comparable.

Comment: Could you explain to me on what is the number field in the priorityqueue constructor for? It is indicated in the API document that it is for initial capacity

Answer (score 0):

Change your line `private PriorityQueue<MyNode<E>> pq` //it is not initialized thats why NPE occurs.

to

```
private PriorityQueue<MyNode<E>> pq = new PriorityQueue<MyNode<E>>();
```

No need to have a `ComparatorMyNode<E>` as a separate class. Instead of this, you can implements Comparable like `MyNode<E> implements Comparable<E>` in your MyNode class and can override the

`public int compareTo(E o) {
        return 0;
  }`

method in your MyNode class.